# On/off switch on mobile has shrinkable width

Tags: bug, status-planned, design, profile-page, responsive-design

The on/off switch widget on mobile doesn't have fixed width and shrinks depending on other elements, e.g. in [settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image]

It's OK for one-line text, but shrinks otherwise.

Comment: Responsiveness. Isn't that what we asked for?

Comment: @rene responsiveless

Comment: That's the price SE (well, we) pay for fancy elements that "look good". Nothing is wrong with the built in checkbox of browsers, but no, it's too simple so need something "special". Anyhow, if they'll have its width static (i.e. doesn't change), it will result in lots of lines of text, which also look bad. Which is less bad? Each and their own taste, no standard.

Comment: As evidenced in the screen shot, the text snippets are reflowed to different lengths already. I can't believe they did this on purpose; there _is_ a rough standard for what on/off sliders should look like and this violates it brutally.

Comment: The little baby switches, they can change color but don't know how to move yet. 

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the report @αλεχολυτ.

The markup for these switches was recently updated across our codebase, but many cases didn't account for shrinking within a flex container. We have a fix in the works that should be live this week.